# Determine if a character exists within a string? (Not using loops)

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to create a funcion that returns *true* if a non-alphanumeric character exists within a string. I cannot use a loop, however, and I'm looking for the right algorithm to do so.

```
not_alphanumeric("hello")  // This would return FALSE
not_alphanumeric("h%llo")  // This would return TRUE
```

I need to know what type of algorithm I need to use in order to do this, OR if there is some non-loop related method in order to do this.

Comment: Considering that you're not allowed to use a loop, is this a homework question? If so, what are the policies around what assistance you're allowed to receive? (Links are helpful here.)

Comment: if you can't use a loop, you probably need to use recursion

Comment: What is the non-alphanumeric character in the second string? Non-alphanumeric means it is neither a number or a letter.

Comment: I fixed the example. I'm not too knowledgeable on recursion.

Comment: You can use `std::any_of` and `std::isalnum` if that's allowed.

Comment: Read up on the algorithms in the standard C++ library, particularly the header `<algorithm>`.

Comment: Of course, `any_of` has a loop in it....

Comment: @Eljay recursion is still a kind of loop.

Comment: You can use `<algorithm>`'s implemetations like `for_each()`, `any_of()` or `find_if()`, even `non_of()` or `<regex>` matching

Comment: @RemyLebeau • then the OP is in a bad place.  The only solution is to manually unroll the loop, and that'll only be as good as how much the loop is manually unrolled.

Comment: Bad professors, and unclear rules. Either it's meant as "use recursion" or as "use a ::std algorithm"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know about the `any_of()` defined in `algorithm` library, you should take a look into it if you're making a program which contains no loops.

Consider this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

bool checkAlphaNum(char *);

int main(void) {
    char *string = new char[1024];

    std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
    std::cin >> string;

    std::cout << checkAlphaNum(string) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

bool checkAlphaNum(char *arr) {
    // verifying each character of the given string argument
    return std::any_of(arr, arr + strlen(arr), [](char ch)
    {return isalnum(ch);});
}
```